# Java Error; array required, but java.lang.String found

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

I am currently trying to complete this program and I'm having trouble with this error. I've done many things trying to fix it so I can compile it but it won't work. It seems that the "String alphabet" is getting the error. Can someone help me solve this please?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Period
{
  private static String phrase;
  private static String alphabet;
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput;
    int[] letter = new int [27];
    int number = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence with a period at the end.");
    userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
    userInput.toLowerCase();
  }

  public void Sorter(String newPhrase)
  {
    phrase=newPhrase.substring(0,newPhrase.indexOf("."));
  }

  private int charToInt(char currentLetter)
  {
    int converted=(int)currentLetter-(int)'a';
    return converted;
  }

  private void writeToArray()
  {
    char next;
    for (int i=0;i<phrase.length();i++)
    {
      next=(char)phrase.charAt(i);
      sort(next);
    }
  }

  private String cutPhrase()
  {
    phrase=phrase.substring(0,phrase.indexOf("."));
    return phrase;
  }

  private void sort(char toArray)
  {
    int placement=charToInt(toArray);
    if (placement<0)
    {
      alphabet[26]=1;
    }
    else
    {
      // here is one spot that mainly the error pops up?
      alphabet[placement]=alphabet[placement]+1;
    }
  }

  public void entryPoint()
  {
    writeToArray();
    displaySorted();
  }

  private void displaySorted()
  {
    for (int q=0; q<26;q++)
    {
      System.out.println("Number of " + (char)('a'+q) +"'s: "+alphabet[q]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us the error you get

Comment: The error is the title. I marked it in my code where it usually shows up

Answer (score 1):

Your `sort` method is treating `alphabet` (the `String`) as an array. `String` is not a `char[]` but you can call [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) like

```
private void sort(char toArray)
{
    char[] alpha = alphabet.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    int placement=charToInt(toArray);
    if (placement<0)
    {
      alpha[26]=1;
    }
    else
    {
      alpha[placement]=alpha[placement]+1;
    }
    alphabet = new String(alpha, "UTF-8");
}
```

But modifying a `String` is not possible, because they are immutable. For the same reason your raw call `alphabet.toLowerCase()` doesn't modify the `alphabet` in your other method.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `alphabet` is defined as a `String` data type, but you need to define it as an array if you want to reference it using the bracket notation `[]` you have in your code. The error message is pretty clear in this case.

```
String[] example = new String[3];
example[0] = "Hello";
example[1] = "ETC...";
```

Comment: What do you mean? Can you specifically show me on my code?

Comment: Or the are after the individual character (like `getCharAt`) but are treating it like an array instead...possibly, maybe...

Comment: @AustinJonMagalong You define alphabet variable as a `new String`. You need to define it as an array. If this explanation is not clear then please consider googling Arrays and Primitives in Java then reading for a bit.

Comment: @Kon oh ok I see now. Thank you haha. That eliminated a lot of my errors. Now all I got left is error on this "alphabet[26] = 1;" It says required: java.lang.String found int.

Comment: @AustinJonMagalong The problem there is you're assigning an `int` data type `1` to a `String[]` element. You may want `String[0] = "1";`. Note that the `26th` index will be out of bounds for an array defined like `new String[26];

Comment: @Kon Oh alright. thanks bro. I've been stuck on this for a while. For some reason though it won't let me run the program still. It keeps saying run Period instead of saying "enter a sentence with a period at the end."